# Use more than one core in bash

Tags: linux, bash, multithreading

I have a linux tool that (greatly simplifying) cuts me the sequences specified in illumnaSeq file. I have 32 files to grind. One file is processed in about 5 hours. I have a server on the centos, it has 128 cores.

I've found a few solutions, but each one works in a way that only uses one core. The last one seems to fire 32 nohups, but it'll still pressurize the whole thing with one core.

My question is, does anyone have any idea how to use the server's potential? Because basically every file can be processed independently, there are no relations between them.

This is the current version of the script and I don't know why it only uses one core. I wrote it with the help of advice here on stack and found on the Internet:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/daw/raw/*
count=0

for f in $FILES
to
  base=${f##*/}
  echo "process $f file..."
  nohup /home/daw/scythe/scythe -a /home/daw/scythe/illumina_adapters.fa -o "OUT$base" $f &
  (( count ++ ))
  if (( count = 31 )); then
        wait
        count=0
  fi
done
```

I'm explaining: FILES is a list of files from the raw folder.

The "core" line to execute nohup: the first path is the path to the tool, -a path is the path to the file with paternas to cut, out saves the same file name as the processed + OUT at the beginning. The last parameter is the input file to be processed.

Here readme tools:
https://github.com/vsbuffalo/scythe

Does anybody know how you can handle it?

P.S. I also tried move nohup before count, but it's still use one core. I have no limitation on server.

Comment: You are starting 31 jobs before waiting. All of them are running simultaneously. If only one core is used, this is due to system limitations, not an issue with your code. While your code can be improved to keep running 31 jobs simultaneously instead of batches of 31, that's not your issue. Talk to your system administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, the most likely solution is **GNU Parallel**, so you can run up to say, 64 jobs in parallel something like this:

```
parallel -j 64 /home/daw/scythe/scythe -a /home/daw/scythe/illumina_adapters.fa -o OUT{.} {} ::: /home/daw/raw/*
```

This has the benefit that jobs are not batched, it keeps 64 running at all times, starting a new one as each job finishes, which is better than waiting potentially 4.9 hours for all 32 of your jobs to finish before starting the last one which takes a further 5 hours after that. Note that I arbitrarily chose 64 jobs here, if you don't specify otherwise, **GNU Parallel** will run 1 job per CPU core you have.

Useful additional parameters are:

- `parallel --bar ...` gives a progress bar
- `parallel --dry-run ...` does a dry run so you can see what it would do without actually doing anything

If you have multiple servers available, you can add them in a list and **GNU Parallel** will distribute the jobs amongst them too:

```
parallel -S server1,server2,server3 ...
```

Comment: Thank U for answer! I will try, but can I open it with nohup? I can't have stable few hours connection with server

Comment: You can run it through `screen` or `tmux` to keep a virtual session open that you can later re-attach to.

Comment: Thank U ! I will try :)

Comment: Use `parallel --dry-run ...` first to be sure of all the filenames and parameters.

Comment: There's an excellent PDF available by Ole Tange (who is the author and regularly on Stack Overflow) if you Google *"gnu parallel 2018 pdf"*