# How to use all cores with a for loop

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a script that processes each file in a directory. Each single execution of `djvu2pdf` takes a lot of time and uses only one of my four CPU cores:

```
for i in  *.djvu; do djvu2pdf "$i"; done
```

To speed up the overall processing I want to run four `djvu2pdf` processes in parallel.

How do I have to change my script that I get four pipelines instead of the presently one pipeline?

Comment: [Exacty your case](https://superuser.com/questions/1025517/bash-for-loop-in-parallel-with-n-cores)
Maybe putting them to background could help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop

Comment: Maybe this is of use ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216475/21425 . Note the example limiting to 'n' cases in parallel

Answer (score 2):

Maybe forking will do the trick for you? You can wrap the main part of the processing into a function, for example like this

```
topdf() {
    local djvu_file=$1
    djvu2pdf "$djvu_file"
}

for i in  *.djvu; do topdf "$i" & done
```

As you can see there is a "&" character which says that the operation should be sent to background.

Comment: Note that if you have, say, 200 tasks, you'll create 200 processes running on 4 cores. That may be an issue if (say) you want a timely, incremental delivery of results

Answer (score 1):

With **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel djvu2pdf ::: *.djvu
```

By default, it will run one job for each CPU core, but you can set more or fewer jobs in parallel with `parallel -j N` where `N` is the number you want.

You can also get a progress bar with `parallel --bar ...`

You can also do a *"dry run"* to see what it would do without actually doing anything with `parallel --dry-run ...`

[See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60812400/2836621).